# What is the direction of Null Vector?

Tags: vectors, definition, geometry

In Physics, we frequently come across the concept of **Null Vector**. Suppose that two forces of equal magnitude act on a block but on opposite directions. In that case, the resultant of the two forces would be said to be a Null Vector. I am asking that what will be direction of a Null Vector, not only in this specific example but in any general situation when a Null Vector comes into discussion. Also will it be correct to assign a direction for a Null Vector as per our convenience while solving a physics problem?

Comment: The same question answered in here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3682/494397

Comment: The direction of a null vector is undefined.

Comment: Direction of a null vector is an oxymoron. If it had direction, it would not be a null vector.

Answer (score 3):

A vector is a mathematical object which contains two components: a *magnitude* component (how big is it) and a *direction* component (which way is it pointing). If its magnitude is zero, then there is *nothing with which to point* and so it's not pointing in any direction at all.